# How to prevent document fields get expended in the firestore database when clicking on document in the firebase console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

Searching for this question, I did not find any solution. When clicking on a document in the firebase console, for some reason, all its fields open expanded. Meaning if you have collection `authors`, and it contains some documents, with the field `photos`, and `photos` is an array of `map`, they all get expended. It takes some time to load, and in some cases is not very convenient, because you have a big list of already opened elements. Is there any way to  show document fields in the console without expending all its elements (by default)?
Here is what I would like to see, when clicking on document:

[image]

Currently, when you click on collection, all documents become expanded:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can set in the Firebase console, whether your arrays/maps to be expanded or not when you open the browser. By default all are expanded. In order to be able to scroll less, collapse the array by simply pressing on the down-arrow in front of your `photos` array.

[image]

But I recommend you to file a feature request for that [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact).